# trying to set up my http.conf file for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-config, web-deployment

I put a folder called simple_cms in my httpdocs directory but my server won't start because my http.conf file is being written wrong how am I supposed to write it.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.webappcompany.com
  DocumentRoot /simple_cms/public    
  <Directory /simple_cms/public>
     AllowOverride all              
     Options -MultiViews           
  </Directory>
```

Comment: What Rails server are you using? Mongrel? Passenger? The setup is different depending on your choice.

Comment: I have Mongrel and Passenger installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the file paths in the `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` commands to the full path from your root directory: `/???/httpdocs/simple_cms/public`.  I'm also using Mongrel + Passenger, and that's what my paths look like.

I've also got a `RailsEnv production` and some SSL stuff in mine, but other that that, yours looks just like it - hopefully it's just the file paths that are holding you back...

Hope this helps!